# How to improve training performances of image Colorization model using Auto-encoders

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, autoencoder

I'm working on an Image colorization model using auto-encoders, here are parameters I'm using :

- `Training` images size:26000
- `Validation` images size:2600
- 40 epochs, it's doing well on first 20 epochs, but not improving on 20 others as described in this picture: [image]
- `Mini-batch size` :32
- `Optimizer` : adam (lr=2e-4)

The input of the auto-encoder is the first dimension of the lab space of the image(gray-scale), and the output is the last 2 dimensions of the lab space(color information), here is a part of my code:

```
IMG_SIZE = 256
N_EPOCHS = 20
BATCH_SIZE = 32
latent_dim = 256

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                                   horizontal_flip = True)

train_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('melange/tr/',
                                              target_size = (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE),
                                              batch_size = BATCH_SIZE)

valid_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

valid_set = valid_datagen.flow_from_directory('melange/vl/',
                                              target_size = (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE),
                                              batch_size = BATCH_SIZE)

def gen_ab_images(train_set):
    for batch in train_set:
        lab_batch = rgb2lab(batch[0])
        X_batch = lab_batch[:,:,:,0] 
        Y_batch = lab_batch[:,:,:,1:] / 128
        yield (X_batch.reshape(X_batch.shape+(1,)), Y_batch)


model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', strides=2, input_shape=(256, 256, 1)))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same', strides=2))
model.add(Conv2D(256, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(256, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same', strides=2))
model.add(Conv2D(512, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(512, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(256, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same'))

model.add(Conv2D(128, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(UpSampling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(UpSampling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(2, (3, 3), activation='tanh', padding='same'))
model.add(UpSampling2D((2, 2)))

valeurs=model.fit(x=gen_ab_images(train_set), 
      epochs=N_EPOCHS, 
      validation_data=gen_ab_images(valid_set), 
      steps_per_epoch=len(train_set),
      validation_steps=len(valid_set),
      shuffle=True)
```

How can I improve the performance of this autoencoder? and also how can I speed-up the training knowing that it lasts really a long time (4.5 hours for 20 epochs and I do it twice) ?

Comment: Well for one you can stop measuring accuracy, it doesn't make sense for an auto-encoder

Comment: You can use tf.data which allow you to prefetch data. You can enable XLA optimisation with https://www.tensorflow.org/xla/tutorials/autoclustering_xla. Mixed precision is another method which makes sense for auto-encoders